# How to fill Table with the list element in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to generate a table with header As Number,Status and count.

then want to fill the table with data from the element obtained from list.

Number will be s.no and status will be the element obtained from list and
 count is number of times the element exits in list.
but i don't know how to generate table in using pdf box and generate pdf.
i have generated pdf normally but dn't know how to make table.
I want to add itr inside table as table data...please help me out

```
public PerformResult perform(CronJobModel arg0)
{
    final String method_name = "getListByStatus";

    LOG.debug("Entering - " + method_name);
    List<String> orderModelList = osiReportGenerate.getStatusList();

    // Check if the order list is empty
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderModelList)) {
        Iterator<String> itr=orderModelList.iterator();
        int y=670,x=600,no=1;

        PDDocument document;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("hello cron job");
            document = new PDDocument();

            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
            //DrawString for Number to pdf
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 10,y );
            contentStream.drawString("Number");
            contentStream.endText();
            //DrawString for status to pdf
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 200,y );
            contentStream.drawString("Status");
            contentStream.endText();
            //DrawString for count to pdf
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 400,y );
            contentStream.drawString("Count");
            contentStream.endText();

            while(itr.hasNext()){
                //for printing numbers.....
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 10,x );
                contentStream.drawString(""+no);
                contentStream.endText();
                no++;
                //For printing status....
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 200,x );
                contentStream.drawString(itr.next());
                contentStream.endText();
                x=x-25;
            }

            PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(document, new        FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\rr.jpg"));
            System.out.println("1");

            System.out.println("2");
            //DrawImage for to pdf
            contentStream.drawImage(ximage,10,680);
            System.out.println("3");


            //contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            Date date=new Date();
            int filename=date.getSeconds();
            document.save("D:\\"+filename+".pdf");
            document.close();


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.SUCCESS, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);
           }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us that code and tell us where are you stuck exactly so that we can help you.

Comment: I've written a small working sample for generating paginated tables that can be found here: http://javamoody.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-paginated-table-with-pdfbox.html

I believe it will be able to help you.